# ¿Como abrir un DialogPreference prográmaticamente?

Tags: android, diálogo

Actualmente puedo abrir un `DialogPreference` definiendolo dentro de un layout:

```
<DialogPreference
    android:key="miDialogo" android:title="Preferencias"
    android:dialogLayout="@layout/fun_layout"
    android:positiveButtonText="OK"
    android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
/>
```

¿Como podría abrirlo desde código?, ya no se tienen método expuestos como `.Show()` o similares...

Comment: Todo elemento que se define en el xml  tiene su definición programaticamente, eso depende de las necesidades del layout, si lo necesitas estático o dinámico, por lo que puedes consultar la API , cuales son los método para que el DialogPreference http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html , sólo necesitas instanciar el objeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que esto ayude, (no puedo probarlo ahora mismo), pero si entiendo su pregunta igual esto le ayuda, si usted tiene una clase `MyDialogPreference` extends de `DialogPreference` cuenta con este metodo:

```
   /**
     * Shows the dialog associated with this Preference. This is normally initiated
     * automatically on clicking on the preference. Call this method if you need to
     * show the dialog on some other event.
     * 
     * @param state Optional instance state to restore on the dialog
     */
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
```

**UPDATE:** O lo que quiere es algo asi como [startPreferencePanel](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#startPreferencePanel)

---

---

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
    doAction((Integer) v.getTag()); 
}
```

.

```
private void doAction(int action) { 

        PreferenceActivity pa = (PreferenceActivity)getActivity(); 

        switch (action) { 

            case ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS: 
                pa.startPreferencePanel(DisplaySettings.class.getName(), null, 
                        R.string.display_settings_title, null, null, 0); 
                break; 
            case ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS: 
                pa.startPreferencePanel(WifiSettings.class.getName(), null, 
                        R.string.wifi_settings, null, null, 0); 
                break; 
            case ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS: 
                pa.startPreferencePanel(BluetoothSettings.class.getName(), null, 
                        R.string.bluetooth_settings, null, null, 0); 
                break; 

            case ACTION_FORCE_STOP: 
                killProcesses(); 
                break; 

        } 
    }
```

Dentro del directorio `settings` en el [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=android_packages_apps-master/Settings/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageDetail.java) puedes mirar las class `DisplaySettings` y demas para ver se adapta a lo que buscas.

---

Variacion sin click

---

```
public void llamada(int testNoClick) { 
        doAction(testNoClick); 
}
```

.

```
private void doAction(int action) { 

        PreferenceActivity pa = (PreferenceActivity)getActivity(); 

        switch (action) { 

            case 1: 
                pa.startPreferencePanel(DisplaySettings.class.getName(), null, 
                        R.string.display_settings_title, null, null, 0); 
                break; 
            case 2: 
                pa.startPreferencePanel(WifiSettings.class.getName(), null, 
                        R.string.wifi_settings, null, null, 0); 
                break; 
            case 3: 
                pa.startPreferencePanel(BluetoothSettings.class.getName(), null, 
                        R.string.bluetooth_settings, null, null, 0); 
                break; 

        } 
    }
```

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=android_packages_apps-master/Settings/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageDetail.java

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a probar esto con pa.startPreferencePanel(). y te comento !

Comment: pues si me ayudo @AngelAngel muchas gracias! saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Escribí [este post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/774310/Show-a-Toast-in-the-Middle-of-the-Android-Screen) (en inglés) que lo explica en detalle.

Resumiendo, el código es:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNose);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: Finish
        Toast tostada = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Usted haz clic, Chico o Chica!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        tostada.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tostada.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero debe ser un DialogPreference, este sería para un mensaje tipo Toast.